# Is there a way to get the elapsed time that a Rails server has been running for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rack, duration

I'd just like to print it out in a HTML view somewhere in my Rails project, along with a bunch of other helpful info. Something like "Current up time = 4d 11h 54m 2s" or "Up since 23rd Aug 2013".

Couldn't find any info on this anywhere, surprisingly. Maybe there's a generic Rack way of doing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do. Create a file, `config/initializers/uptime.rb`, with:

```
YourApplication::BOOTED_AT = Time.now
```

Then it's just a case of comparing the current time to that time, which you can easily do in a helper method, using the `time_ago_in_words` rails helper:

```
def uptime
  time_ago_in_words(YourApplication::BOOTED_AT)
end
```

This gives you a human readable string saying how long the  application has been running (give or take a few seconds for the startup).